# Dynamically created button not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created rows of table Dynamically by jquery, I also add a remove button on each row,and add an event on this button by which the row corresponding to that button(in a row) is removed when we click on that button,But my broblem is only upper three buttons are active and fired,and the buttons which are at last are not able to work.

```
$(function(){ 
    $('<input></input>')
        .attr({'type': 'button'})
        .val("Remove")
        .appendTo('table#AllSelectedTest tbody tr:first td:last')
    ; 
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("table#AllSelectedTest tbody tr input").live({
        click: function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
        }
    })
});
```

I uses The above code For Generating a button and bind it with the events.
My Problem is some button works and some are not

Comment: Moreover, it would be helpful if you could give your old code.

Comment: I edited my question and add my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its always good to give an id to element. try changing the code as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $('<input>').attr({type: 'button', id:"remove_button", value:'Remove'})
                     .appendTo('table#AllSelectedTest tbody tr:first td:last');

   $("#remove_button").live("click", function(){
                         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
});
```

fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/vSUYj/1/

also if you are using jquery above 1.7, please make use `on` instead of `live`.

**update:** try this as well, in case above not working

```
 $(document).ready(function(){   
       var elem = $('table#AllSelectedTest tbody tr:first td:last');
       elem.append('<input type="button" id="remove_button" value="Remove"/>');

     $("#remove_button").live("click", function(){
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     });
 });
```

fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/vSUYj/

Comment: i use this function also,But still now only top four buttons are active,and the buttons which are below 4th position are not working

Comment: <input id="remove_button" type="button" value="Remove" ,=""> in html code it looks like that

Comment: actually its not correct format.. try the new answer i have updated in answer

Comment: By the way i correct it ,but still only top 4 buttons works rest of them i think is disabled

Comment: well then create a jsfiddle.net with your code and post here.. it will easy to find out the problem.

Comment: shit man.. there was an extra "}". i have updated the answer, its working fine.. check the fiddle example. both the above answers are working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it's impossible to say for certain, but are you using [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to assign the handlers for those buttons?

edit: should also be noted that those methods are deprecated in the latest version of jquery, and the new method is [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I tried your solution But still now only top four buttons are active,and the buttons which are below 4th position are not working,

this is the strange thing for me,I dont know what happens here